# When using array i get Nullexceptionerror

Tags: java, arrays

I hope you guys could help me out with the program processing. I'm building a random image generator using an array. I made an integer called number which gives a random one using the random() function.

Could you take a look at my code and tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thank you all.

Here it is

```
//WINDOW SCREEN SIZES
int wBreedte = 500;
int wHoogte = 600;

void setup() {
  //LOAD IMAGES
  PImage image0;
  PImage image1;
  image0 = loadImage("mario.jpg");
  image1 = loadImage("peach.jpg");

  //ARRAY FOR RANDOM IMAGE
  PImage image[] = new PImage[2];

  //RANDOM IMAGE NUMBER
  int number = (int)random(0,2);

  //WINDOW
  size(wBreedte, wHoogte); 

  //DRAW IMAGE
  image(image[nummer], 30, 30);
  println("Random number image: " + number);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code here & the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Post your code here. If your code is "too long" then you need to create an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn'y assign the images to the array:

```
void setup() {

  ...

  //ARRAY FOR RANDOM IMAGE
  PImage image[] = new PImage[2];

  image[0] = image0;
  image[1] = image1;

  ....
}
```

or more concise:

```
void setup() {
      //removed image declarations

      PImage image[] = new PImage[2];
      image[0] = loadImage("mario.jpg");
      image[1] = loadImage("peach.jpg");

      ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant line 22 to be uncommented - you never assigned any images to `image[0]` or `image[1]`, so you're passing null in to the `image()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you explain me how i assign images to image[0] and image [1]?

Comment: Maybe you need to get yourself a book or an elementary tutorial.